# how to solve equation over positive integers in WolframAlpha?

Tags: wolframalpha

I can get WolframAlpha to solve an equation over integers, for example "x+y=3 over integers", but I can't figure out how to force WolframAlpha to solve it over positive integers

Comment: x > 0, y > 0 perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like this works: [wolfram alpha link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%7Bx%2By%3D3,%20x%3E0,%20y%3E0%7D%20over%20integers)

```
solve {x+y=3, x>0, y>0} over integers
```